# How to connect a JavaScript function to a property signal?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm new to Qml and having some trouble connecting a javascript handler to a property's signal. I have a C++ object with a property and signal.

```
class CppObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant value READ getValue WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged)

signals:
    void valueChanged(const QVariant &);
};
```

The objects are created through a C++ factory method and I'm able to bind the values
and changes to Qml properties.  This all works.

```
property CppObject obj: cppProxy.PropertyFactory("foo");

Text
{
    x: 100;
    y: 100;
    text: parent.obj.value;
}
```

For some properties, I'd like to connect the valueChanged signal to a javascript function.
I've been up and down through the Qml documentation and have tried a bunch of stuff without
any luck.  I figured something like this should work, but doesn't

```
function objEventHandler()
{
    console.log('objEventHandler() ran')
}

Component.onCompleted:
{
    obj.value.valueChanged.connect(objEventHandler);
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can also connect as you've tried in your example, but the form is:

```
Component.onCompleted:
{
    obj.valueChanged.connect(objEventHandler);
}
```

The signal is not a property of the 'value' object, but of 'obj'.

Comment: One additional complication I came across is that "this" is not always well defined in signal handlers if you're getting a signal from C++. So, in this example I had to use a closure to retain access to the "obj" context, like this: `Component.onCompleted: { var o = obj; obj.valueChanged.connect(function() { console.log(o.text); }); }`

Answer (score 2):

It's simple using the connections object.

```
Connections
{
    target: obj;
    onValueChanged: console.log('changed');
}
```